# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompatEclair.class

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':jobFlexwithInvoice:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException:duplicateentry:android/support/v4/view/MotionEventCompatEclair.class

i have this problem and my gradle file is,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studity.socet_store"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

what should i do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this..

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0') {
exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

> Instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

or exclude module:  to other where problem create

Comment: it gives me an error(35,0) ==> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: I think you need to remove this from gradle.. compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') and try with clean and rebulid with your own code