# Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{module=support-v4}]

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run my application with instant run turned off but I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompatEclair.class

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jua.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile project(path: ':app_Data')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408660/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-android-support-v4-view-keyeventcom) thread:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar'){
    exclude module: "support-v4"
}
```

And now I am receiving this error when I try to Sync now gradle.build:

> Error:(29, 0) Could not find method exclude() for arguments
>   [{module=support-v4}] on file collection of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.
>   Open File

I am a little lost right now, If anyone has any idea how to solve this I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I removed

> compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

completly and I still get the first error.

Comment: Not sure of the solution, but it looks like `compile(){ exclude module }` does not apply if you use `files`. e.g. `compile(){exclude}` works, but `compile files(){exclude}` will not. Is it possible to include the dependency from a repository instead of locally?

Comment: I removed it completly and I still get the first message. Any ideas?

Comment: ... so you want to add the support lib then remove the support module?  What does that leave?  Also `FileCollection` does not have an exclude method: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html

Comment: Worth a read [Resolving Conflicts in android gradle dependencies](https://medium.com/mindorks/avoiding-conflicts-in-android-gradle-dependencies-28e4200ca235)

Answer (score 34):

This is a syntax issue. The closure in which you are calling exclude is being interpreted as an argument to the files() method, which is incorrect. Should look like this

```
compile (files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')){
  exclude module: "support-v4"
}
```

Comment: same applies for `compile project(':project name')` as `compile (project(':project_name')){ exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same problem, I deleted android-support-v4.jar from folder and now it works. For some reason, if you remove it from inside the gradle.build file it continues to create problems.