# Could not find method exclude() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used to have

```
implementation(group: "com.domain.package", name: "lib-name", version: "$ver") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.google.dagger'
}
```

When I import as aar

```
implementation (files('libs/lib-name.aar')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.google.dagger'
}
```

I got the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=org.apache.commons}] on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency.
```

Wonder what went wrong?

Note: I have check on [Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{module=support-v4}]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770540/could-not-find-method-exclude-for-arguments-module-support-v4), which ensure the extra parenthesis is there, that I have done. But it is not helping.

Comment: Any update on this one?  I keep getting the same...

Comment: Currently running into the same issue. Is there any update on this?

Answer (score -2):

the problem might be the parenthesis location:

try:

```
implementation (files('libs/lib-name.aar'), {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.google.dagger'
})
```

in step of

```
implementation (files('libs/lib-name.aar')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.google.dagger'
}
```